# laravel 5.1 Artisan::call() parameter --tag for vendor:publish not working

Tags: laravel, console, publish, laravel-artisan, vendor

im using console to call multiple vendor to publish my seeding data, but unfortunatelly i got this error

### try 1

```
Artisan::call('vendor:publish',
[
    '--provider' => 'Package\MyPackage\CoreServiceProvider',
    '--tag' => 'seeds',
    '--force' => true
]);
```

error message

```
[ErrorException]                         
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

### try 2 (success without tag parameter)

i remove --tag and no error

```
Artisan::call('vendor:publish',
[
    '--provider' => 'Package\MyPackage\CoreServiceProvider',
    '--force' => true
]);
```

when i run code on my terminal it's fine `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Package\MyPackage\CoreServiceProvider" --tag=seeds --force`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after more trial and error i got solutions,

i must use array for `--tag` parameter

```
Artisan::call('vendor:publish',
[
    '--provider' => 'Package\MyPackage\CoreServiceProvider',
    '--tag' => ['seeds'],
    '--force' => true
]);
```